# VS2010: Add company name, etc. to a DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have built a DLL in VS2010, but I did not find any option to include a company name, copyright, etc. that would be visible if one inspects the file info for the DLL.

Can somebody tell me where this can be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Copyright of the binary? Well... In general, look in the Manifest options.

Comment: Is there no field that you allow me to simply insert my company name and another to add the copyright info, etc? As in VB6?

Comment: Last time I've used VB6 was literally *years* ago, so I simply don't remember anything about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Codeproject article about adding resources to a dll:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37133/Simple-Version-Resource-Tool-for-Windows

Or an alternative:

http://pisoft.ru/verstak/insider/cw_ver1.htm

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a resource to the project.  Right click on the project and select `Add\New Item...`.  In the Visual C++ section go to `Resource` and select `Resource File`.  In the resource view (`view\Resource view`) right click on the resource you've just created and select `Add Resource...`.  In the list select `Version`.

You will then have a window appear with key value pairs.  You can edit fields, such as FileVersion, LegalCopyright etc.